# Undefined reference to symbol 'FcPatternAddDouble' - issue with building program

Tags: command-line, 13.04, compiling, make, makefile

I'm Ubuntu 13.04 user. I haven't been able to build/install Japanese third-party software for artists called *AzDrawing*. Based on readme file, I executed **make** command in proper directory. At first it was going well, but after a while command-line aborted its work and displayed information:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/draw/CFont.o: undefined reference to symbol 'FcPatternAddDouble'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'FcPatternAddDouble' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1: could not read symbols: invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [azdrawing] Error 1
```

What should I do? I'm Unix beginner, so bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

FcPatternAddDouble comes from fontconfig, and if the symbol / function or maybe class is undefined, this is probably because you didn't install libfontconfig1-dev  ?

Then, retry to build your software. If not found one more time, you can try :

make distclean  # removes everything, including Makefile missing fontconfig headers

./configure # add your options

make

If this does not solve yor issue, try :

apt-cache search fontconfig

... and install what could be missing

Last but not least : try to provide some feedback to the guys providing the software, and dont forget to tell them there is probably an issue with build dependencies ;-)

HTH

-- ericb